# Is it possible to do hot-deploy on websphere with Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, websphere

It's easy to manage a Tomcat server using Netbeans in order to do hot-deploy of web applications. Is there a way to do the same things for a websphere instance using Netbeans 6.9? It does not appear in the supported servers list, and I didn't find any plugin to handle it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When targetting Websphere IBM tend to prefer you to use RAD, which has built in integration.

Comment: It's a pity that you can't choose to use your favorite IDE when you're tied to a specific server ;). I guess I don't have much other choices...

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use ant script specific tasks. You also have to make your app reloadable. Someone was lucky just providing external source for app in websphere and edit in locally.